# how to dismiss the UIPopoverController from another viewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I have created a UIPopoverController and added it to a  main view controller when clicking an setReminder button  popoverView working fine. i want dismiss popupview if i click a save button how can i do?
[image]

```
  **mainView.m**
-(void)btnSetReminderTapped:(id)sender
{
setReminderView =[[setReminder alloc]initWithNibName:@"setReminder" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

setReminderView.delegate = self;
FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:setReminderView];
popover.tint = FPPopoverDefaultTint;

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400,400);
}
else {
    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 288);
}
popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionUp;

//sender is the UIButton view
[popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];
}

  ***setReminder.m***

- (IBAction) btnSaveTapped:(id) sender
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delegate to notify your main view on `btnSave` action and dismiss in that delegate.

```
@protocol EventDelegate <NSObject>

- evenSaveButtonClicked;

@end
```

In your main ViewController implement it as

```
- (void) eventSaveButtonClicked{
    [popover dissmissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)btnSetReminderTapped:(id)sender
{
setReminderView =[[setReminder alloc]initWithNibName:@"setReminder" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
setReminder.delegate = self;
setReminderView.delegate = self;
FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:setReminderView];
popover.tint = FPPopoverDefaultTint;

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400,400);
}
else {
    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 288);
}
popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionUp;

//sender is the UIButton view
[popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];
}
```

You have to create a delegate inside your SetReminder Class

```
@interface SetReminder

@property(nonatomic, unsafe_unretain) id<EventDelegate> delegate

@end
```

and in implementation file(.m) you can sythesis it as follow

```
@implementation SetReminder
@synthesis delegate

// Your button save code
- (IBAction) btnSaveTapped:(id) sender
    {
         if([delegate respondToSelector:@selector(eventSaveButtonClicked)]){ 
             [delegate eventSaveButtonClicked];
         }
    }
```

@end

Comment: I have done with code implementation you can check it once again